# CollectionView get rid from spacing between columns

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have following layout (white inside cell is imageview)

[image]

The problem is that I want to get rid of vertical white line, which is background of collection view.

I try the following code, but it doesnt work

```
class membersVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var screenSize: CGRect!
var screenWidth: CGFloat!
var screenHeight: CGFloat!

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    screenWidth = screenSize.width
    screenHeight = screenSize.height

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth / 2, height: screenWidth / 2)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5


}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 6
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) ->
    UICollectionViewCell! {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("membersCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! membersCell

        cell.bg.image = UIImage(named: "membersCell")

        return cell
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried setting the background color of the collectionView to the same color as the cell borders?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

Comment: what is the expected layout ?

Comment: I mean to say, what is the layout you want to obtain ?

Comment: i want decrease horizontal spacing between cells and get rid of vertical line at the center of the screen

Comment: So you want a bigger collectionView cell. Tried stretching the width of cell to half of screen in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

1) Set the layout insets to left and right values according to your needs. This will move the items to the center.

2) Decrease the whole with of the collection view and center it in the middle.

If you need scrollindicators on the screen edges you need solution 1).